# trouble with proof of the binomial theorem

Tags: calculus, induction

Below is Spivak's solution to his question to prove the binomial theorem. It is  solution (d). From 'Then', there are 4 steps. I could only understand the first two. I do not understand how j is replaced by j-1 and how n became n+1. It would really help if someone were to suggest intermediate steps to arrive at that result.

> The binomial theorem is clear for $n=1$. Suppose that
>
> $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j$$
>
> Then
>
> \begin{align}
> (a+b)^{n+1}&=(a+b)(a+b)^n=(a+b)\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^{j+1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}{n\choose j-1}a^{n+1-j}b^j\ \text{(replacing }j \text{ by } j-1 \text)\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j
> \end{align}

Comment: The replacement of $j$ by $j-1$ is just an "index shift."  If you were to write out each of the terms in both, they would look the exact same.  $a_1+a_2+a_3$ could be described either by $\sum\limits_{k=0}^2a_{k+1}$ or it could be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^3a_k$ or it could be $\sum\limits_{k=100}^{102}a_{k-99}$ etc...

Comment: The second part, recognize that $\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$, the paschal identity.

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP asks a very specific question, trying to clarify a misunderstanding about sigma notation; @RichardAmbler provides a specific answer to that specific question, namely "intermediate steps to arrive at the result".  At least this isn't yet another "do my exam problem for me" question that disappears the moment it's answered...

Comment: @JohnHughes I think it might be because the question originally contained a scanned image of the problem. Some of us appear to be a bit quick to down-vote minor issues that could be easily rectified, which sometimes results in surprisingly poor scores for legitimate questions once the said issues are rectified...

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to write out the first few terms of the sums $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} a^{n-j}b^{j+1}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {n\choose j-1} a^{n+1-j}b^{j}$ to convince yourself that they are equivalent.

Alternatively, note that in both expressions $j$ is a dummy variable that has no significance outside the sigma notation. It might be helpful, then, to give the dummy variable it a different name, say $u$,  in the second sum.

That is, for the sum

$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j} a^{n-j}b^{j+1}$$

Let $u=j+1$, then when $j=0$, $u=1$; when $j=n$, $u=n+1$. Then just express the $j$ in the general term appropriately in terms of $u$. You should get:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{u=1}^{n+1} {n\choose u-1} a^{n+1-u}b^{u}$$

But since $u$ is a dummy variable, we could as easily have called it $j$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $j=i-1$ so that when $j$ goes from $0\dots n\,$, $i=j+1$ goes from $1 \dots n+1$. Then:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} a^{n-j}b^{j+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{i-1} a^{n-(i-1)}b^{(i-1)+1} =  \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{i-1} a^{n+1-i}b^{i}
$$

Of course, you can replace $i$ with $j$ in the last sum, since the index of the sum is just a placeholder.