# Proof of the binomial theorem by induction clarification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

This is an exercise from Spivak's "Calculus".

> 3.d. Prove the "binomial theorem": If $a$ and $b$ are any numbers and $n$ is a natural number, then
>
> \begin{align} (a+b)^n &= a^n + {n \choose 1}a^{n-1}b + {n \choose 2}a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots + {n \choose n-1}ab^{n-1} + b^n \\ &= \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} a ^{n-j}b^j \end{align}

The solution is given as

> The binomial theorem is clear for $n=1$. Suppose that
>
> $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j$$
>
> Then
>
> \begin{align}
> (a+b)^{n+1}&=(a+b)(a+b)^n=(a+b)\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^{j+1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}{n\choose j-1}a^{n+1-j}b^j\ \text{(replacing }j \text{ by } j-1 \text)\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j
> \end{align}

My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065614/trouble-with-proof-of-the-binomial-theorem), but it is not about the change of indices. What were the steps to combine the two summations at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Pascal's rule:

$${n\choose j}+{n\choose j-1}={n+1\choose j}$$
So we have
\begin{align}
(a+b)^{n+1}&=(a+b)(a+b)^n\nonumber \\
&=(a+b)\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^j\nonumber \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j +\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n\choose j}a^{n-j}b^{j+1}\nonumber \\
&={n\choose 0}a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^n{n\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}{n\choose j-1}a^{n-j+1}b^j\nonumber \\
&={n\choose 0}a^{n+1}+{n\choose n}b^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[{n\choose j}+{n\choose j-1}\right]a^{n-j+1}b^j\nonumber \\
&={n+1\choose 0}a^{n+1}+{n+1\choose n+1}b^{n+1}+\sum_{j=1}^n{n+1\choose j}a^{n-j+1}b^j\nonumber \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose j}a^{n+1-j}b^j\nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your response @Maryam! I'm aware of the rule, but how was it applied across these two summations? Since $n$ and $j$ are variables of the summations, how could they be factored out and added separately?

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm going to explain that in my answer.

Comment: It is just distributivity of the multiplication over addition: $\sum_{i,j}\alpha f(i,j)+\sum_{i,j}\beta f(i,j)=\sum \alpha f+\beta f=\sum (\alpha +\beta)f$

Comment: @Maryam: If you use \left[ and \right], you get square brackets that are automatically sized to match what’s between them.